How would I Fix a rotating 3D Cube in SwiftUI?
To preface this question, I would like to mention that I'm only a month or so into swiftUI. I was previously using React Native for my projects, so pardon my unfamiliarity with standard swift practices.
Code:
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

let transforms = [
    // Front face
    CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0, 50),
    // Right face
    CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DMakeTranslation(50, 0, 0), CGFloat.pi / 2, 0, 1, 0),
    // Top face
    CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, -50, 0), CGFloat.pi / 2, 1, 0, 0),
    // Bottom face
    CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 50, 0), -CGFloat.pi / 2, 1, 0, 0),
    // Left face
    CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-50, 0, 0), -CGFloat.pi / 2, 0, 1, 0),
    // Back face
    CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0, -50), CGFloat.pi, 0, 1, 0)
]

struct TransformableView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var views: [AnyView]
    @Binding var angleX: CGFloat
    @Binding var angleY: CGFloat

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let container = UIView()
        container.backgroundColor = .clear


        // Apply perspective to the container
        /*
        var perspective = CATransform3DIdentity
        perspective.m34 = -1.0 / 300
        container.layer.sublayerTransform = perspective
         */

        for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
            let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
            hostingController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
            hostingController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
            hostingController.view.layer.transform = transforms[index]
            container.addSubview(hostingController.view)
        }
        
        return container
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        let rotationX = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angleX, 1, 0, 0)
        let rotationY = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angleY, 0, 1, 0)
        let combinedRotation = CATransform3DConcat(rotationX, rotationY)

        
        // ISSUE HERE MAYBE?
        uiView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

        uiView.layer.sublayerTransform = combinedRotation
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var angleX: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var angleY: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var lastAngleX: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var lastAngleY: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        TransformableView(views: [
            AnyView(Rectangle().fill(Color.red)),
            AnyView(Rectangle().fill(Color.green)),
            AnyView(Rectangle().fill(Color.purple)),
            AnyView(Rectangle().fill(Color.yellow)),
            AnyView(Rectangle().fill(Color.blue)),
            AnyView(Rectangle().fill(Color.white)),
        ], angleX: $angleX, angleY: $angleY)
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    // Update the angles based on the drag amount
                    angleX = lastAngleX + value.translation.height / 300
                    angleY = lastAngleY + value.translation.width / 300
                }
                .onEnded { value in
                    // Store the last angles when the gesture ends
                    lastAngleX = angleX
                    lastAngleY = angleY
                }
        )
        .background(.pink)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


The code generates a 3D cube using swiftUI transformations, and rotates the cube according to user gestures. The code is supposed to anchor the cube to the center of the screen but the cube strays off both vertically and horizontally.
Image of cube straying off course
The image provided above shows the cube translating off course and not staying fixed.
Already I've tried to go through various routes to get a rotating cube(fixed in place).
I've tried:

using the metal, however would not work for my purposes since I would like to place views on each of the surfaces of the cubes.
Using rotational3D

Resources used:
This article was really helpful for getting started.
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/135/how-to-render-uiviews-in-3d-using-catransformlayer
I've also looked at Aheze's prism code
https://github.com/aheze/Prism/tree/main
However, from what I can tell it looks like his renderer is not truly producing a 3d cube but just imitating one.

What's wrong with "imitating" a 3D cube? Aren't everything 3D "imitated"? The screen is flat.

@Sweeper I mean "imitating" in the sense that it's not really a 3D object because it cannot fully rotate 360 degrees. Aheze's prism code(from what I understand) extrudes a cube to only 3 faces.
I require a full cube with all 6 faces, that can be rotated fully.
